# template subclassing with partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Consider the following

```
template<typename Type, size_t Dimensions> 
struct Base 
{  
     Base(/*some args*/)  {   /*do something*/  }
};

template<size_t Dim>
class Derived : Base<double,Dim> {};
```

Derived doesn't inherit the constructor of the Base because it suggests that Base is a partial specialization and therefore requires some different constructor. However this is not so in my case. I mainly want it to have different name in different situations. I'm looking for a solution different than macros or the following one, if exists.

```
template<size_t Dim>
struct Derived
{
  typedef Base<double, Dim> Type;
}
```

mainly because I don't like using

```
Derived<n>::Type
```

everywhere and not sure I want to

`typedef Derived<n>`

for every n I use.

Comment: `template<size_t Dim> using Derived = Base<double, Dim>;`, now just use  `Derived<n>`.

Comment: this helps, many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
template<std::size_t dim>
using foo =  typename derived<dim>::type;
//usage
foo<n> bar;
```

This takes advantage of the C++11 template using statements

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: `typename T` -> `size_t Dim` ?

Comment: `C++14`? I think they were introduced in `C++11`

Comment: The comment posted by @ildjarn is also probably a good way to go depending on if you need to add any functionality within `derived` or not. If `derived` is merely a new name for the specialization use that method, but if `derived` needs to add functionality my answer can help

Comment: many thanks! it was helpful, actually both of them acceptable right now....and now I need to understand why in this\your case
`template< size_t D>
void fun(Derived<D> x){/*do something*/}` doesn't deduce the `n` from `Derived<n> x(args);`  and must to be called  `fun<n>(x)`. (using  @ildjarn 's approach it works without <n>)

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky add the updated code either to your question or as an answer so we can see what the issue is?